# prism tabbed content and the ribbons

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism, ribbon

I'm developing a prism application with a ribbon bar on the top, a outlookbar on the left and a tabbed content region (tabcontrol with regionadapter).

I'm using the view injection.

My problem now is: how to inject the tabitem's own tabcontrol (e.g. edituser button) into the ribbon when switching from one existing tabitem to another one.

I think INavigationAware is not working in this scenario. (right?)

The only approach I could imagine is to hook into the tabheader and do stuff there.

I'm glad of every solution you could give me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are your ribbonbar, outlookbar, etc. in different modules? Are you looking for a way to communicate a tab change to the ribbon?

Comment: That's exactly what want to achieve. And yes, they are in different modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read your response to my question and think Prism's `EventAggregator` can help you.  It's designed to faciliate inter-module communication, among other functions as well.  Here's a sample of how you can use it:

Get an instance of the EventAggregator. I'm using dependenct injection here:

```
// Ctor injection
private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
public YourViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
    _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
}
```

Create an event to publish (parameter is for a payload).  In your case a tab selection:

```
public class TabSelectedEvent:CompositePresentationEvent<object>{}
```

Publish the event when a tab is selected;

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<TabSelectedEvent>().Publish(null);
```

Finally, subscribe to the event and respond:

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<TabSelectedEvent>().Subscribe(OnTabSelectedEvent);
```

Now, you should be good to go.

Comment: I know the basics on how to communicate between modules. The problem in this case is, that I need to hook into the TabItem's events. But I would prefer a solution where the viewmodel / controller detects the navigation event (Like INavigationAware with view discovery).

Comment: I believe INavigateAware will not work for a tab control.  You can use an AttachedBehavior to hook into the tab events and respond accordingly.  I'll update my answer if you need an example.

Comment: I now got a solution with an attached property of type boolean. I attach it to the tabcontrol. Within the PropertyChangedCallback I hook into the selectionchanged handler of the tabcontrol. Within this hook I get the selected tab and check if the datacontext of the tab is of my own type ITabNavigationTarget which implements a method that handles the ribbon injection. Is that what you meant? Or are there other and better solutions?

Comment: Yes,that's what I meant and I'm sure there are other ways to do it as well.  I think I still prefer using the EventAggregator for your situation.